# json file not found when unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-import

I have a python file and a helper json file. The json is loaded via

```
with open("scraper_dbs.json") as f:
    scraper_dbs = json.load(f)
```

From my testfolder I want to test the file which looks like

```
from path.to.file import function
```

On this import statement I get the error
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'scraper_dbs.json'

When I run the python code itself it finds the json and continues on.
What do I miss?

Comment: Is scraper_dbs.json present along side the test file ?

Comment: Where are you running your tests from? From the main directory or the test directory? If you're running the tests from the test directory your relative path should go up till the main directory first. Personally I always prefer to run the tests from the main dir.

Comment: try to open `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'scraper_dbs.json')` instead.

Comment: Reply of @Cpt.Hook did the trick. Thanks a ton